# Get up-down control from buddy?

Tags: c, winapi

Is it possible to get a handle to an up-down control from a handle to its buddy? So [`UDM_GETBUDDY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759913%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) is not an option.

Thanks!

Comment: The fact that you can't do this tells you that you are doing this wrong. You are meant to remember the up-down control that you made. Try not to forget it!

Comment: I want to handle `WM_KEYDOWN` on the edit control and `UDN_DELTAPOS` on the up-down control. Therefor I would need an identifier for each control. I hoped to use just one, by getting the identifier of the up-down control from a handle to its buddy for use in a switch statement in `WM_KEYDOWN`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would the buddy window know or care about the up-down control?

There are probably several workarounds you can use:

- Store the handle in the buddy's window with GWL_USERDATA or SetProp()
- Give the u/d control a id relative to the buddy (id+1 or id+1000 etc) and use GetDlgItem
- Enumerate all the windows in the dialog and ask every u/d control.

Comment: I thought about the first and third options too, but the second one is what I'm using now (but I use | (OR), not +). Thanks!